# React Native ошибка билдинга проекта

Tags: react-native, expo

У меня есть проблема с модулями, но я не знаю из-за какого именно модуля не билдится проект (ошибка появилась после того как я установил модули, они у меня сразу пачкой). Я использую EXPO, однако я не могу добавлять по одному модулю и вновь пытаться делать билд, так как на 1 билд уходит не менее 20 минут (очередь + сам билд), я использую команду `npx-cross-env EAS_NO_VCS=1 eas build -p android --profile preview`, подскажите, что мне делать?

Вот модули, которые я устанавливаю через yarn:

```
yarn add @expo/vector-icons @react-native-async-storage/async-storage @react-native-community/masked-view @react-native-community/slider @react-native-masked-view/masked-view @react-navigation/bottom-tabs @react-navigation/native @react-navigation/native-stack axios cheerio expo expo-app-loading expo-asset expo-av expo-constants expo-
device expo-font expo-image-picker expo-navigation-bar expo-notifications expo-permissions expo-screen-orientation expo-
splash-screen expo-status-bar expo-updates expo-video-player react-native-safe-area-context react-native-screens react-n
ative-snackbar-component react-native-svg react-native-web react-native-webview socket.io-client
```

Полный лог, который я имею по итогу:

```
Running 'gradlew :app:assembleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android

Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.1-all.zip

10%.

20%.

30%.

40%.

50%.

60%.

70%.

80%.

90%.

100%

Welcome to Gradle 8.0.1!

Here are the highlights of this release:

 - Improvements to the Kotlin DSL

 - Fine-grained parallelism from the first build with configuration cache

 - Configurable Gradle user home cache cleanup

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/release-notes.html

To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.

Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build

[stderr] 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

[stderr] 
* Where:

[stderr] 
Settings file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/settings.gradle' line: 10

[stderr] 
* What went wrong:

[stderr] 
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'testapp'.

[stderr] 
> path may not be null or empty string. path='null'

[stderr] 
* Try:

[stderr] 
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr] 
> Run with --info or --debug

[stderr] 
option to get more log output.

[stderr] 
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[stderr] 
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

[stderr] 
BUILD FAILED in 18s

Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```